# Why is Uint8List compatible with list<int> in dart?

Tags: dart

I am a dart newbie.

Something strange I noticed while learning dart is that `Uint8List` seems to be compatible with `List<int>`.

For example, the `IOSink.read()` method accepts data of type `List<int>` as an argument. But it also seems to accept data of type `Uint8List` as argument directly.

What kind of mechanism is this? It doesn't really convert every `byte` in the `Uint8List` to `int`, does it? That would be very wasteful in terms of efficiency and memory usage.

Comment: [`Uint8List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) implements the `List<int>` interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Uint8List` interface implements `List<int>`.

That means that it has an implementation of every member of `List<int>` with a signature that is compatible with `List<int>`.
It also means that `Uint8List` is a subtype of `List<int>` and a `Uint8List` instance can be used anywhere a `List<int>` instance is allowed or required.

Making `Uint8List` implement `List<int>` was easy, since a `Uint8List` is a list of (limited) integers, and because Dart only has one integer type, `int`, there is no problem distinguishing between a "byte" and an integer.

Any integer you read out of a `Uint8List` will be in the range 0..255.
Any integer you write into a `Uint8List` will be truncated to its first 8 bits before being stored. Storing the integer 257 into a `Uint8List` means actually storing the byte with value 1.

The `read` method will likely just use plain `List` methods for storing integers into the buffer. If that buffer happens to be a `Uint8List`, those integers are truncated and take up only a single byte. If not, it just stores integers (which happen to be in the range 0..255) into a `List<int>` as normal.

Comment: Issues arise if you try to convert utf-16 strings into Uint8List as int get truncated to lowes 8 bits.